# check if a specific message is still in the channel? - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been working on creating a connect 4 game for my discord bot, the game itself works fine,
but if someone removes the message that contains the Board and the reactions which are used by users to play the game, the game will start to break and won't work as it should until someone restarts the bot:

```
turn = 0 #switches between 0 and 1 during the game

game_over = False
while not game_over:
    try:

        reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check = check)
        if turn == 0:
            #do stuff depending on what the emoji reaction is
            if winning move():
                game_over = True
        else:
            #do stuff depending on what the emoji reaction is
            if winning_move():
                game_over = True
        #more things that aren't necessary to show
```

Is there a way for me to change the `game_over` to True after someone removes the message and/or check if the message has been deleted and change the variable to True through that?
for e.g:

```
#If the board's not in the channel:
  await message.channel.send("Board was not found")
  game_over = True
```

any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asyncio.wait()` function.
See an example below where I have implemented simple mini-game logic.

```py
@client.command()
async def mini_game(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("test message")  # send first message
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
        [
            asyncio.create_task(client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=your_check)),  # specify `your_check` function
            asyncio.create_task(client.wait_for("message_delete", check=lambda m: m == message))
        ],
        return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,
        timeout=30  # you can specify timeout here
    )
    if done == set():
        pass  # if time limit exceeded
    else:
        coro = done.pop().result()
        try:
            reaction, member = coro  # if user `member` has added `reaction`
        except TypeError:
            pass  # if message has been deleted
```

You can adapt this code to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a message has been deleted by simple trying to fetch the message with the id it had before being deleted. If this returns a `NotFound` error, the message has been deleted:

```py
def is_message_deleted(ctx, message_id):
    try:
        await ctx.fetch_message(message_id) #try to fetch the message
        return False
    except discord.error.NotFound: #if a NotFound error appears, the message is either not in this channel or deleted
        return True
```

You can then include this function in your code:

```py
if is_message_deleted(ctx, board_message.id):
    await message.channel.send("Board was not found")
    game_over = True
```

References:

- [context.fetch_message()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.fetch_message)